# Gatsby extend ESLint rules overwrites original ESLint

Tags: eslint, gatsby

I am following the directions in the documentation https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/eslint/, and would like to overwite one of the rules, but not affect the others, what I did is create an `.eslintrc.js` file.

This is the content of the file

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true,
  },
  extends: `react-app`,
  "rules": {
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': [
      'error',
      {
        handlers: [
          'onClick',
          'onMouseDown',
          'onMouseUp',
          'onKeyPress',
          'onKeyDown',
          'onKeyUp',
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

but the rest of the rules are now ignored, like it was not an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer above is correct, it is a bit incomplete. The thing is eslint can be integrated both in builds and editors.

When you start using a custom `.eslintrc.js` you will lose the integration on build and output in the terminal based on those rule. That's because the built-in eslint-loader is disabled when you use a custom file. It actually says so on the documentation page but it is a bit unclear.

To get that back, you will need to integrate it in the webpack build. The easiest way is using the [plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-eslint/) mentioned on the doc page: `gatsby-plugin-eslint`.

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23666) to make custom integrations easier.

Answer (score 1):

From the Gatsby docs you linked to:

> **When you include a custom .eslintrc file, Gatsby gives you full control over the ESLint configuration. This means that it will override the built-in eslint-loader and you need to enable any and all rules yourself.** One way to do this is to use the Community plugin gatsby-eslint-plugin. This also means that the default ESLint config Gatsby ships with will be entirely overwritten. If you would still like to take advantage of those rules, you’ll need to copy them to your local file.

So it looks like as soon as your create a `.eslintrc.js` file, you need to build your rules up from the bottom again. It overwrites, it doesn't extend.

Comment: Hi @luc. I am adding in the eslint file to extend react-app. According to the documentation, this way "You’ll replicate (mostly) the ESLint config Gatsby ships with so you can then add additional presets, plugins, and rules.". What I am trying to do is keep the original eslint rules but overwrite this one.

Comment: The base Gatsby eslint file has quite a few more rules beyond extending the `react-app` rules. Here is the actual base config: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/src/utils/eslint-config.ts. You can copy paste the rules to your eslintrc.

Comment: I will check and let you know. Thank you

Comment: this this not work for me, copying and pasting the whole content into .eslintrc.js only made all warning disappear, like no rule being applied